# PHP: Giving file to user is very slow

Tags: php, download, http-headers

```
<?php
//Part of auto_include.php Start
//ROOT Var Start
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
//ROOT Var End

//DB Start
include($root.'/engine/conn_db.php');
//DB End
//Part of auto_include.php End

$file_key = $_GET['file_key'];

if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `id_key`='{$file_key}'")) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $file_key           = $row->id_key;
        $file_name          = $row->name;
        $file_size          = $row->size;
        $file_mime          = $row->mime;
        $file_path_rel      = '/get/'.$file_key.'/'.$file_name;
        $file_path          = $root.$file_path_rel;

        $file_exist = true;
    }
}

if($file_exist == false) die();

//If Get
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-store');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header("Content-Length: $file_size");
header("Content-Type: $file_mime");
header('Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100');
header('Server: Apache');
//If Load
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: $file_size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

readfile($file_path);
?>
```

I am trying to return file to user for viewing in the browser, if this possible, including mp4 videos. It's works, but slow asf with long videos (around 50min). Getting them with direct link noticeably faster, also then in network tab (inspector) it's loaded more than one time with various Content-Range headers.

And if other headers used (under `//Load`) then file dowloading in the background. I can see save window only after it's finish downloading, like on mega.nz.

Comment: You're fetching all results, even if you've found the file. You could add a `break;` after `$file_exist = true;`.

Comment: @Syscall Doesn't help.. It still needs more than 12secs for load.
http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/18/0128/h_1517138433_8319185_8d2e989f3d.png